# NSRunAlertPanel causes memory leak

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application, I uses NSRunAlertPanel to confirm the quit by the user.

When I run my application under instruments to detect memory leaks, it shows memory leak in the following code.

```
 -(void)CloseWithConfirm
 {
     int answer;
     //Here, it is showing memory leak.
     answer = NSRunAlertPanel (@"Quit Confirmation", @"Do you want to quit?", @"Yes", @"No", @"Cancel"); 

     if(NSAlertDefaultReturn == answer)
          [self close];          
 }
```

Any clue on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSRunAlertPanel is actually calling `runModalForWindow:` and creating a modal event loop. Even though hitting the confirmation button on the modal window dismisses the window, it doesn't destruct the modal loop that was created. In your return if statement try doing this:

```
if (NSAlertDefaultReturn == answer) {
   [NSApp stopModal];
   [self close];
}
```

See if the memory leak stops with this code.

FWIW, since you are closing down the app when this method exits, having a memory leak right at the end probably isn't affecting things too much.

Comment: apple is not using [NSApp stopModal]; in there sample projects.

Comment: Thanks MySpecialPurpose for the answer. It looks like this memory leak is now gone.